# How to share code between 20 vue.js applications?

Tags: vue.js, architecture, lerna, monorepo

I know that there are tools like lerna and rushjs.
My prerequisites are:

I have ~20 repositories with vue applications generated via vue-cli. Those repositories are private on bitbucket.

There are components, that may be used in any of these repos, such as form elements, form layouts and so on.

Also there may be huge amount of code (services, helpers, constants), that may be shared across these repos. These repos are vue multi-step forms, that have same structure and logic.

What is the best way to organize this?

Answer (score 1):

You can [create your own private node module](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages) and place all the shared code (components, services, helpers, constants) in there, then you can simply include it as a dependency in each of your Vue projects and use it as necessary.